# Sporadic bugs in multidimensional SparseArray objects

Tags: matrix, bugs, version-9, sparse-arrays

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0**

---

**Update**

This `SparseArray[]` bug is (apparently) fixed on version 10.0

```
$System//Print;
$Version//Print;

Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)
10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)
```

Thanks, Wolfram!

---

**Resolution**

- WRI affirms that `SparseArray[__]` is broken (in 9.0 and 9.01)
- WRI's suggested workaround is `SparseArray//Normal`

My experience with this particular `SparseArray` bug has been that reliable coding requires that the `Normal` workaround be applied to *every* instance of `SparseArray`, because the failures of `SparseArray` are sporadic, occult, and associated to unknown preconditions.

Ouch!

My thanks are extended to all who commented.

---

```
Wolfram Technical Support 
email: support@wolfram.com
Re: [CASE:646986] 
    Sporadic bugs (?) in multidimensional `SparseArray` objects

Hi John,

Thank you for getting back to us.

I understand that for now your temporary workaround 
of `aTest = aTest // Normal` is holding the fort.

Our developers are working on this issue and 
we anticipate that the resolution will appear 
in the future release of Mathematica.

Sincerely,

<name redacted>

Wolfram Technology Group
Wolfram Research, Inc.
```

---

What appear to be sporadic bugs (?) in multidimensional `SparseArray` objects (?) are plaguing our code development efforts.

```
$Version//Print;
9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)
```

The following code elicits wrong answers and/or kernel crashes:

```
Do[
    (* aTest is a SparseArray[...] that crashes the kernel and/or
       yields incorrect results unless wrapped in Normal[...] *)

    aTest = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1], {2,2,2,2}] +
        I*RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1], {2,2,2,2}]//
      SparseArray[
          {
              {i_,j_,k_,1 ,i_} :> #[[k,1,i,j]]*#[[k,2,1,j]],
              {i_,j_,k_,2 ,j_} :> #[[k,1,i,j]]*#[[k,2,2,i]],
              {i_,j_,k_,n_,j_} :> #[[k,1,i,j]]/;Equal[n-2,i]
          },
          {2,2,2,4,2},
          Complex[0.0,0.0]
      ]&//Flatten[#,1]&//
        Transpose[#,{4,1,2,3}]&//
          Flatten[#,2]&//
            Transpose;

    (* enable the following line to "fix" aTest *)
    (* aTest = aTest//Normal; *)

    (* the following all should be 0.0 (to machine precision) *)

    (aTest//Normal)-aTest//
      Flatten//Abs//Max//Print["      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = ",#]&;

    id = SparseArray[{i_,i_}\[Rule]1,{16,16},0];
    (aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id//
      Flatten//Abs//Max//Print["(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =",#]&;
,{10}];
```

**Results** (when the kernel doesn't crash immediately)

```
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =7.43925
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =3.14861
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =1.27373
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =1.8666
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =2.03269
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =3.26388
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =1.30013
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =3.14138
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =0.953447
      (aTest//Normal)-aTest =?= 0 = 0.
(aTest//Normal).id-aTest.id =?= 0 =0.841252
```

**Remarks** Variants of the above code crash/fail for Complex-valued and Integer-valued SparseArrays; apparently the multidimensionality is the essential trait.

Help, advice, and workarounds all are appreciated!

Comment: This is clearly a bug, present in version 9.0.1.  I can reproduce the crash if your input is the very first thing I evaluate after a kernel restart.  Otherwise I can reproduce the wrong results.  You might want to report it to tech support.  I'd like to note that version 8.0.4 doesn't have this bug.

Comment: That's what we see too ... furthermore, for *some* dimensionalities SparseArray seem to work OK ... that's why it's been pretty tough to track-down this sparse-matrix behavior.  It's concerning (to me) that occult traces of this sporadic behavior may still be affecting our results, and so I wish I know exactly *what* preconditions elicit this bug (if it is a bug).

Comment: I observe this behavior is also present in V9.0.1. Definitely should be reported to WRI.

Comment: What is the best way to report bugs to WRI? (over the years, my experiences in this regard have been uneven).

Comment: @JohnSidles Write to support at wolfram.com.  When you are certain that something is a bug, there's little use posting on this site, as this is not an official WRI site.  The only thing people can do here is try to come up with workarounds.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have followed your suggestion.  When you say: "The only thing people can do here [on Mathematica StackExchange] is try to come up with workarounds", that is not quite true!  The StackExchange is cross-indexed, searchable, archival, publicly responsive, and rapidly verifying ... and these valuable qualities are much-appreciated.  Thanks are extended to all who commented!

Comment: Update: WRI is working on this bug: emails to "support at wolfram.com" with the subject "Re: [CASE:646986] Sporadic bugs (?) in multidimensional `SparseArray` objects" will be forwarded to the WRI development team.  NOTE: there's no need to cc: me ... for my purposes the workaround of wrapping with "Normal" is acceptable.

Comment: @JohnSidles You can post this as an answer so that the question won't stay in the unanswered list.  (Unless you are looking for additional workarounds.)

Comment: @Szabolcs ... self-answer posted per your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The bug is fixed in MMA 10.0 (see original question for details)

---

Answering my own question per [Szabolcs' sugggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43633/sporadic-bugs-in-multidimensional-sparsearray-objects#comment131458_43633):

**Answer**

- WRI affirms that `SparseArray[__]` is broken (in 9.0 and 9.01)
- WRI's suggested workaround is `SparseArray//Normal`

My experience with this particular `SparseArray` bug has been that reliable coding requires that the `Normal` workaround be applied to *every* instance of `SparseArray`, because the failures of `SparseArray` are sporadic, occult, and associated to unknown preconditions.

My thanks are extended to all who commented.